# incorporate wordpress into a website

Tags: html, wordpress, web, blogs

Can you please shed some light on incorporating word press into the site.

Here my requirement is..i have a tab called 'my blog' in my website.

When the user clicks that button he able to see the name of my blog

and my posts and archives and also tags..these much information i want.

I don't want to use complete word press in my site.

Comment: You need to customize your own wordpress theme ?

Comment: No sir..when the user clicks the button, he able to see my blog name,posts of mine and he also able to archive and comment also..how can i do that..please help me sir

Comment: Is it on a server or wordpress.com ? There is a folder in your blog/wp-content/themes/yourtheme with php and css files, open them ?

Comment: say..i have www.example.com/blog. when the user clicks on blog tab. he able to see  content of my blog means blog name,posts,archives rather than whole wordpress, and also he can comment to my posts..can happen like this..thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is really simple. Follow my instructions.

1. Login to your cpanel.
2. Create a folder named `blog` in your root.
3. Upload the latest version of wordpress you downloaded from
   [WordPress.org](http://wordpress.org/).
4. Unzip it to the blog folder. (Make sure to move all files outside
   the folder `wordpress`)
5. Create a MySQL database and add a user to it. Make sure to keep the
   database name, username and password. For most of the server the
   hostname will be localhost.
6. Now go to www.example.com/blog and just follow the instructions
   there and Run the installer.
7. Now you can login into your WordPress Dashboard.
8. Search google for some free wordpress themes and install one of the
   themes in Theme section in Dashboard.
9. Now your wordpress blog is ready. In your site for the `blog` tab
   give the link as www.example.com/blog.

**Reference Links:**

[Famous 5-minute installation - WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress)

Cheers !!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are self-hosting, and have access to your controls;

You will need to create a new MySQL database, and safely store your database name, username, hostname and password for later.

You will have to download wordpress http://wordpress.org/, and follow the installation instructions also found at http://wordpress.org/.

In order to do what I think you're wanting to do, you will need to create a new theme by creating a new folder in your Content > Themes folder, and move ALL your site files into this new directory.

Add to your CSS file to make it an applyable 'theme':

```
/*
Theme Name: 
Theme URI: 
Author: 
Author URI: 
Description: 
Version: 
License: 
License URI: 
*/
```

You will then have to assign this new theme to Wordpress, and create at least two template files,

```
category.php
single.php
```

Within these two templates is where you will loop through your posts, and display your full posts, respectively.

This isn't a graceful solution, however, it will do what you want it to in a rudimentary way. It would be better to develop a proper theme for your site, and fully take advantage of Wordpress as a CMS, and not just a blogging platform. There are lots of resources on how this is done, and it may seem overwhelming but start small, that's how you learn.